# Unable to bind data in Mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I am trying to use <foreach> but facing some issue.Code is as follows:

**Bean.java**

```
private class Bean{
 private String clientId;
//getter and setter 
}
```

**Dao.xml**

```
<mapper namespace="...Dao">
    <resultMap id="bean" type="...Bean">
        <result property="clientId" column="CLIENT_ID" />
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getData" resultMap="bean" 
         parameterType="someBean">

             SELECT * 
             FROM tableClient                                       
            WHERE CLIENT_ID        IN 
            <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list"
                open="(" separator="," close=")">
                trim(#{clientId})
                </foreach>
    </select>
</mapper>
```

The query intend to return data in:

```
    List<Bean> getData(List<Bean> bean);
```

Although the query is executing successfully but the exception is raised when the data is binded.Stacktrace :

```
2013-03-23 15:11:13,637 DEBUG  [getData] ==>  Preparing: SELECT * FROM tableClient WHERE CLIENT_ID IN ( trim(?) , trim(?) , trim(?) )  


2013-03-23 15:11:13,637 DEBUG  [SqlSessionUtils] Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@117c0eb] 
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'clientId' not found. Available parameters are [list]


2013-03-23 15:11:13,637 DEBUG  [DataSourceUtils] Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource 
at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:365)
at $Proxy11.selectList(Unknown Source
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that in your list there is beans with a clientId attribute and getter, you have to replace `trim(#{clientId})` with `trim(#{item.clientId})` as you defined your bean on the `foreach` by item.

Comment: Yes..thanks!I should have also understood the same from the Exception itself